# SharpGL: Can't draw all lines from List

Tags: c#, winforms, opengl, sharpgl

I have:

```
float[,] nodesN = null; //indexes:
                        //number of node;
                        //value index 0->x, 1->y, 2->temperature
int[,] elements = null; //indexes:
                        //indexof element (triangle)
                        //1, 2, 3 - vertexes (from nodesN)
List<Pair> edges = null; //Pair is a class containing two int values which are
                         //indexes of nodesN
```

And function which is supposed do all elements and edges on `SharpGL.OpenGLCtrl`

```
    private void openGLCtrl1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        gl = this.glCtrl.OpenGL;
        gl.ClearColor(this.BackColor.R / 255.0f,
            this.BackColor.G / 255.0f,
            this.BackColor.B / 255.0f, 1.0f);
        gl.Clear(OpenGL.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | OpenGL.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    }

    private void openGLControl1_OpenGLDraw(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        gl.Clear(OpenGL.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | OpenGL.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        gl.LoadIdentity();
        gl.Translate(0.0f, 0.0f, -6.0f);

        if (!draw) return;

        bool drawElements = false;

        if (drawElements)
        {
            gl.Begin(OpenGL.TRIANGLES);

            for (int i = 0; i < elementNo; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
                {
                    float x, y, t;
                    x = nodesN[elements[i, j], 0];
                    y = nodesN[elements[i, j], 1];
                    t = nodesN[elements[i, j], 2];

                    gl.Color(t, 0.0f, 1.0f - t);
                    gl.Vertex(x, y, 0.0f);
                }
            }

            gl.End();
        }

        gl.Color(0f, 0f, 0f);            

        gl.Begin(OpenGL.LINES);

        //for(int i=edges.Count-1; i>=0; i--)
        for(int i=0; i<edges.Count; i++)
        {               

            float x1, y1, x2, y2;
            x1 = nodesN[edges[i].First, 0];
            y1 = nodesN[edges[i].First, 1];

            x2 = nodesN[edges[i].Second, 0];
            y2 = nodesN[edges[i].Second, 1];

            gl.Vertex(x1, y1, 0.0f);
            gl.Vertex(x2, y2, 0.0f);                
        }   

        gl.End();          
    }
```

But it doesn't draw all the edges. If i change `drawElements` it draws different number of edges. Changing `for(int i=0; i<edges.Count; i++)` to `for(int i=edges.Count-1; i>=0; i--)` shows that esges are generated correctly, but they are not drawn.

Images:
`for(int i=0; i<edges.Count; i++)`
`drawElements=false`
http://img225.imageshack.us/img225/9295/noup.jpg

`for(int i=edges.Count-1; i>=0; i--)`
`drawElements=false`
http://img828.imageshack.us/img828/9595/nodown.jpg

`for(int i=0; i<edges.Count; i++)`
`drawElements=true`
http://img64.imageshack.us/img64/4929/withup.jpg

`for(int i=edges.Count-1; i>=0; i--)`
`drawElements=true`
http://img833.imageshack.us/img833/9167/withdown.jpg

What is wrong with this? How can I draw all edges?

**EDIT:**
Never mind, I dropped SharpGL and wrote exactly the same code in OpenTK. It works excelent without me wondering what was wrong. This was a good call because SharpGL uses enormously big amount of memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once I had a very similar problem.

It was due to z-buffer. If you have a plane and want to draw it's wireframe than the coordinates overlap and artifacts like those arise. It's numerically undefined behavior - drawing two objects on the same depth. You never know which one comes on top.

One solution is to offset the wireframe a bit. I noticed that in some 3d modelling packages. In game engines it's also common to offset sprites on geometry (gunshot marks on a wall). Another might be disabling the z-buffer and manually occlude hidden lines.

The case when you disable drawing of elements might be to another issue with z-buffer. It's bounded by far and near clipping planes. Most probably you draw the lines exactly at the depth of one of them (my guess is far one).

EDIT. I read Your code a bit. One I'd like to see is how You construct the projection matrix. If you didn't touch it at all than (If I recall correctly) the near and far clipping planes are at -1.0 and 1.0 respectively. But, I might be wrong since You draw at z=-6.0...

The other thing, try replacing:

```
gl.Vertex(x1, y1, 0.0f);
gl.Vertex(x2, y2, 0.0f);
```

With something along the lines of:

```
gl.Vertex(x1, y1, 0.01f);
gl.Vertex(x2, y2, 0.01f);
```

Comment: Nice shot, but I'd be surprised... Why would the error appear also without the rectangle at the background? And with the rectangle, on depth test set to LEQUAL, why would consistent linear interpolation of only 0's yield anything other than 0 in the z-coordinate?

Comment: Sometimes numerical errors arise due to numerical instability of algorithms. Since OpenGL T&L pipeline contains many transformations before anything hits the color buffer than there's a lot to go wrong along. And I'm sure OpenGL isn't using continued fractions or any numerically super-stable contraptions since it's performance oriented. You know, something along the lines: 0.2 + 0.6 = 0.8000007.

Comment: Could You also include initiazitaion code? The one containing projection matrix.

Comment: This can't be value issue. It draws (or not) the lines depending of direction of iteration. So this has to be some memory issue. If this was value issue it would be drawn the same way regardles of order of drawing. I noticed that this library has some memory bug so I dropped it. I use OpenTDK now and everything works perfectly :)